# Android / Java find the correct library for a particular class

Tags: java, android

How can I figure out which class needs to import which library?
For example, I see a sample code like below:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

When I try this code Android Studio throws that RequestQueue and Volley cannot resolve.
Is there any documentation, wiki, a website for finding out the correct import library for these classes?

Comment: Did you add volley dependency to the gradle ?

Comment: You have to know beforehand why you want to use a particular library and what you want to achieve from it. There are either native android libraries which you can simply press 'alt+enter' to import it, or other third-party libraries which you need to compile into your 'build.gradle' file.

Comment: @ManishNegi yes I added and it is working right now but I googled for this. I was wondering there is a wiki or any documentation for finding this error.

Comment: After adding the dependency did you sync the gradle ? If you haven't synced gradle, you won't be able to use library classes.

Comment: @ManishNegi It is working properly now. Thanks

Comment: Before you use some library, you should anyhow know what it does and what its limitations are and which license is used. So searching for the documentation is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a search for the class on google. So in this case, search for the class 'RequestQueue' on google and the second result itself gives you the package. Here, it is com.android.volley package.

http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that you can use for parsing and this code is related to Volley library to remove that error you must check that library is in your project or not.

Check your `build.gradlefile(App)`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

If above line is there then you can use that library